# Regular Expression is working for php not for JavaScript

Tags: regex

This is my expression:

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])[[:graph:]]{6,25}$
```

I have tested it on http://regex101.com/

Its working for string `DeepakManwal1` when there is `php` selected but does not work when `javascript` is selected. I don't know what is the exact reason.

I want to use this expression for `password` validation where there should be at-least one uppercase letter and one numeric character.

Here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/j7rmj44h/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of the POSIX class `[:graph:]` — you could change it to the equivalent `[\x21-\x7E]`. Also, you need to remove the quotations around your pattern according to your fiddle.

```
var re = /^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])[\x21-\x7E]{6,25}$/
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/j7rmj44h/3/)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, javascript doesn't understand POSIX.

Have a try with:

```
 ^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])\S{6,25}$
```

Answer (score 1):

Different regex engines have different capabilities. Only the simplest of regex can be shared across implementations.

If I recall correctly `[:graph:]` like specification of character classes is not supported in JS.